# Vectorization of index for flat nested datastructure

Tags: python, indexing, linear-algebra, vectorization

Is there a function in linear algebra that takes vector `[a, b, c]` and returns the vector `[bc, c, 1]`? Or perhaps `[abc, bc, c]` or `[abc, bc, c, 1]`?

For homework I am vectorizing an indexing function, I take the in-product of vector `[abc, bc, c, 1]` (where the letters represent the maximum value for a certain dimension) with vector `[0, A, B, C]` (where the letters represent the wanted index for each dimension) which results in the index for the flat data structure.

I want to vectorize getting to the indexing vector `[abc, bc, c]` as well, but I can't come up with a matrix or vector that creates it from my first vector `[a, b, c]`.

I use python.

Comment: Doing it with a for-loop should be near trivial.

Comment: Yes its not intricate at all, but the point of the homework is to vectorize everything.

Comment: X:[a,b,c] -> Y:[abc,bc,c] transformation using matrices : X*M*(X*Xt) = Y. with M matrix chosen accordingly (just write every variable m_ij). Xt is transpose vector of X

Comment: Im trying it now. Do you mean Xt*X instead of X*Xt? Assuming X is a row vector, if you do X*Xt you get powers of 3 after multiplying it with X*M.

Comment: @georgesl Solving it is very hard, havent succeeded yet. Is it possible?

Comment: @georgesl I got it, but the equation you suggest only works for the first term. For each next term a new (and easier) equation can be made. If Y=y1+y2+y3 you get: 
I x M xt x e1 = [abc,0,0] = y1, and:
I xt x e3 e2 = [0,bc,0] = y2, and:
I x e3 = [0,0,c] = y3